# What is a good way to create a file using ANT and overwrite if file exists?

Tags: file, ant, file-handling

I need to create a file with ANT and overwrite the file if it already exists.

```
<touch file="myfile.txt"/>
```

can be used to create the file but it won't overwrite if the file exists already.

One approach to achieving what I want is

```
<touch file="mytempfile.txt"/>
<move file="mytempfile.txt" tofile="myfile.txt"/>
```

but I wanted to know if there was a better way to do this maybe a single ant task.

Comment: The `touch` task, much like the shell command it mimics, either creates nonexistent files or updates the modification time of existing files. Ant doesn't have a task that will delete and touch all at once (I think most people would find this dangerous and rarely useful). If you need to do this often, you can create a `macrodef` for convenience. Let me know if you need help with that, and I can provide it as an answer.

Comment: Yeah creating a `macrodef` would be great. I think I'll help myself with that. Thanks for the suggestion though @CAustin  :)

Comment: I reckon <concat destfile="myfile.txt"><string value=""/></concat> will do it.